# registry entry access from native ntdll

Tags: c, boot, regedit, ntdll, runonce

is there a document which let me know what are the HKLM registry hives are accessible from Native C++ program. I am writing a C program which will run using BootExecute and will access read / write reg entries. I could do it successfully under \Registry\Machine\System\ControlSet001\Services however if I am trying to access 
\Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce 
or
\Registry\Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

it fails. Is there a document or information which helps me to let know what all registry are accessible during OS boot, will be helpful.

Comment: wich code fails? Wich one is the error?

Comment: \Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce fails

Comment: i mean... what is the fault code?

Comment: STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND. That is the reason in my question my ask is, if there is a MS document which can let me know what all Hives are available from Native ntdll before boot (for those Programs Running using BootExecute)